# dvc push, change the names of files on the remote storage

Tags: dvc

I'm working on a project with DVC (Data Version Control), when I push files in my remote storage, the name of the files are changed. How I can conserve the names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: there is no way to do that.

Long answer:
Dvc remote is a content-based storage, so names are not preserved. Dvc creates metafiles (*.dvc files) in your workspace that contain names and those files are usually tracked by git, so you need to use git remote and dvc remote together to have both filenames and their contents. Here is a more detailed explanation about the format of local and remote storage https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/internal-files#structure-of-the-cache-directory . Also, checkout https://dvc.org/doc/use-cases/sharing-data-and-model-files